# How to update state in an ObservableObject array in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an array of ObservableObjects. I have a button that increments a value property in each object in a list.

My problem is that the UI isn't updating when the published property is changed by tapping the button. If I add a new item, I'll see the updated value changed.

How do I have the UI update when I tap the button?

```
class Item: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var value: Int = 1
    let id = UUID()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items: [Item] = []
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($items) { $item in
                Button {
                    item.value += 1
                } label: {
                    Text("\(item.value)")
                }
            }
            
            Button("Add Item") {
                items += [.init()]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Binding is for value types you need an ObservedObject wrapper in a subview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a different approach, using `ObservableObject`
for your data model that has the array of `[Item]` structs.

Have a look at this  **official** link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)

Example code:

```
class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = []
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var value: Int = 1
    let id = UUID()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var dataModel = DataModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($dataModel.items) { $item in
                Button {
                    item.value += 1
                } label: {
                    Text("\(item.value)")
                }
            }
            Button("Add Item") {
                dataModel.items.append(Item())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [workingdog's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77771714/5133585) suggests, you should try making `Item` a struct. In general, structs work much better with SwiftUI's APIs, so you should only use classes when it is absolutely necessary.

If classes cannot be avoided, you can use `@Observable` instead of `ObservableObject`s. Just change `Item` to this and SwiftUI can automatically detect changes in `Item`.

```
@Observable
class Item: Identifiable {
    var value = 1
    let id = UUID()
}
```

---

Before iOS 17, you would need to wrap an additional `ObservableObject` around the array, and detect any changes to the `Item`s yourself, using Combine or otherwise. When you detect a change, call `objectWillChange.send()` to let SwiftUI know.

Here is a rough example:

```
class Items: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var items: [Item] = []
    // dictionary, so that removing items can be easily done
    private var cancellables: [UUID: AnyCancellable] = [:]
    
    func addItem() {
        let item = Item()
        items.append(item)
        cancellables[item.id] = item.objectWillChange.sink { [weak self] _ in
            self?.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    func removeItem(_ item: Item) {
        items.removeAll { $0.id == item.id }
        cancellables.removeValue(forKey: item.id)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var items = Items()
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items.items) { item in
                Button {
                    item.value += 1
                } label: {
                    Text("\(item.value)")
                }
            }
            
            Button("Add Item") {
                items.addItem()
            }
        }
    }
}
```