# How to avoid SwiftUI redraws with model data

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to better understand how SwiftUI does redraws when using an observable object as model data.

Hear an example. I have `arc4random_uniform` in my InputView so I can see when a redraw happens. This works as I would expect, and only redraws the view that's focused when typing.

```
struct InputView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("", text: $text)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            Text("\(arc4random_uniform(10000))")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text1: String = ""
    @State var text2: String = ""
    @State var text3: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            InputView(text: $text1)
            InputView(text: $text2)
            InputView(text: $text3)
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I try to do the same thing using an array of observable objects that hold my binding strings, it redraws all the views when you're typing in one.

```
class Document: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = []
    
    init(items: [Item]) {
        self.items = items
    }
    
    class Item: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
        @Published var text: String = ""
        let id = UUID()
    }
}

struct InputView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("", text: $text)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            Text("\(arc4random_uniform(10000))")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var document = Document(items: [.init(), .init(), .init()])
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach($document.items) { $item in
                InputView(text: $item.text)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to have SwiftUI only redraw the views that are being changed when I'm using model data like this.

Comment: I recommend to use the line `let _ = Self._printChanges()` rather than a random number. By the way `arc4random_uniform` is outdated. In Swift there is `Int.random(in:)`

Comment: Unlike the first example where you have 3 `@State`s, `Document` only has one `@Published` property. SwiftUI can't "look inside" the array to determine what actually changed. Similar to [what I said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77772640/5133585) to your previous question, how about using `@Observable`? It would work as you expect here.

Comment: To actually have a fair comparison between `StateObject` and `State` here, you would change the first code snippet to use `@State var texts = ["", "", ""]`, and now the behaviour is consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI updates views based on a dependency graph. When things that a view depends on changes, SwiftUI updates that view. In the second example, Each `InputView` depends on the published property `document.items`. SwiftUI knows this because you passed `$document.items` to the `ForEach`. So when `document.items` publishes a value, all `InputView`s are updated.

Why doesn't SwiftUI see that each `InputView` depends on different key paths of `document`? Well it certainly *can* be designed that way, but `ObservableObject` is not designed to do that. You are not supposed to "nest" `ObservableObject`s like this in the first place.

`@Observable` gives a much finer-grained way for SwiftUI to observe changes, and hence build much finer-grained dependency graphs. This is your code using `@Observable` instead of `ObservableObject`, and it works the way you expect. Each `Item` object's `text` is tracked separately.

```
@Observable
class Document {
    var items: [Item] = []
    
    init(items: [Item]) {
        self.items = items
    }
    
    @Observable
    class Item: Identifiable {
        var text: String = ""
        let id = UUID()
    }
}

struct InputView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("", text: $text)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            Text("\(Int.random(in 0..<10000))")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var document = Document(items: [.init(), .init(), .init()])
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(document.items) { item in
                @Bindable var bindable = item
                InputView(text: $bindable.text)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The more general way to "stop a view from updating if nothing has changed" is [`equatable()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/equatable()). You can conform `InputView` to `Equatable`:

```
struct InputView: View, Equatable {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs.text == rhs.text
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then add the `equatable()` modifier when using it:

```
ForEach($document.items) { $item in
    InputView(text: $item.text)
        .equatable()
}
```

Now `InputView` will only update when the `InputView` you create after its parent updates is *different* (as determined by `==`) from the `InputView` before its parent updates.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI doesnt "draw" it recomputes `body` when changes are detected which is negligible since everything is values on the memory stack. The before-change-body and after-change-body are diffed and the result is used to init/deinit/update UIKit `UIView` objects for us automatically and it's those that do any actual drawing. You could make your code more efficient for SwiftUI to diff by making `Item` a struct so it is a value too. e.g.

```
class Document: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = []
    
    init(previewing: Bool) {
        if previewing {
            items = Item.sampleData()
        }
    }

    func load() {

    }

    func save() {

    }
    
    struct Item: Identifiable {
        var text: String = ""
        let id = UUID()
    }
}
```

If you are working with documents I'd recommend taking a look at [Building a Document-Based App with SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/building_a_document-based_app_with_swiftui) it uses `FileDocument` which is the SwiftUI value type which when diffed results in a `UIDocument` object behind the scenes.

Comment: I'm trying to recreate UI I made in UIKit for SwiftUI. It involves a lot of text areas. The issue is SwiftUI constantly recomputes all my subviews when any part of the model changes. I can do this in UIKIt so only the active views get recomputed but struggling to get the same effect in SwiftUI with model data.

Comment: SwiftUI recomputes much more often yes but it doesn't matter because it doesn't actually do anything unless there is a difference in the values since last time it was recomputed. Since everything is just values on the memory stack its all negligible performance-wise.  When there is a difference then it inits/updates/deinits UIView objects for you automatically. You can make the diff more efficient by making your `View` `body`s  as small as possible.